# Is it possible to run Karma unit tests against a prebuilt Angular package?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

Currently I have an Angular application built on top of [NG6-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter). The NG6-Starter uses webpack to bundle the application. It also supports unit testing by default via Karma, but karma uses webpack as well in order to get all the sources injected to it's browser.

Now, my issue is, that I would like to add my application to a classic CI/CD pipeline: Some static analysis, then package build, then unit tests, then etc, and I do not want to break the principle of "Test against the artifact that you are going to deploy" principle. Since karma currently builds the application for itself, it does not really rely on the artifact, that is going to be deployed, even though by the stage karma runs, it is already built.

My question is, if you have any idea/practice/example/experience with this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems so, that in order to achieve this, the spec files should be built with webpack during build time. For this, the easiest way seemed to be to simple introduce a new chunk entry point to the application.

Comment: Do you have any further reading on this topic? I'd like to decrease the time it takes to run our CI pipeline, and by doing this will shave off a few minutes